Signature Error When Integrating VNPay in .NET Core
Create paymentULR
////////////////////
Signature Error When Integrating VNPay in .NET Core
I am integrating VNPay into my .NET Core project and encountering an issue with an invalid signature. Below is the code I am using to generate the signature and retrieve the IP address:
public static String HmacSHA512(string key, String inputData)
{
    var hash = new StringBuilder();
    byte[] keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
    byte[] inputBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputData);
    
    using (var hmac = new HMACSHA512(keyBytes))
    {
        byte[] hashValue = hmac.ComputeHash(inputBytes);
        foreach (var theByte in hashValue)
        {
            hash.Append(theByte.ToString("x2"));
        }
    }
    
    return hash.ToString();
}

public string GetIpAddress()
{
    string ipAddress;
    try
    {
        ipAddress = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"].FirstOrDefault();
        
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress) || (ipAddress.ToLower() == "unknown") || ipAddress.Length > 45)
        {
            ipAddress = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ipAddress = "Invalid IP: " + ex.Message;
    }
    
    return ipAddress;
}

[I have confirmed that TmnCode and HashSecret are correct.](https://i.sstatic.net/zOHSoz35.png)
When I send the request, I receive an invalid signature error.

